# What are all cases that user can revoke (run time) permissions ? (in Activity Lifecycle)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm working with permissions and I'm trying to make calling stuff requiring permissions easier than asking if there are permissions every time...

User can revoke permissions once is asked for them - than it's clear how to handle it, but the problem is when user goes to apps menu (during app work) and revokes given permissions...

I assume that there's only 2 ways to revoke permissions:
1 - when user is asked for them and refuses to grant
2 - when user goes to the menu and app settings switching off permission

The question is: is there any other way to revoke permissions ??
Can any other app (or whatever else) working in background revoke permissions (at any time ?) without our knowledge when our app is in Resumed state ?

I'm asking as if there are the only 2 scenarios we will know that app can not loose permissions without calling onPause() (to go out to menu or display on top permissions granting dialog).
It would make us able to don't ask for granted permissions over and over again until onPause() has been called.

Comment: Afaik, the only ways to revoke the permissions are those two that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Other apps can't modify your app's permissions.

If you need to account for user toggling them manually through app settings, perhaps you need to verify permissions every single time you use an API that requires those permissions.

Also please note that permissions changed significantly with API 23.

Answer (score 0):

I know that API 23 introduced the run time permissions - that's the case of the topic...

OK, so You're saying that no other app can change my app permissions, so it means that there's no way to revoke them before onPause() will be called.
What if I will set some global boolean checking if onPause() has been called ?
If not set (no onPause() has been called) I would not need to check permissions before calling stuff requiring it as I assume there's no way permissions has been revoked :>

I assume Android Studio will warn me to ask anyway, but I think that there would be some way to get rid of the warning...
It would simplify the code

if (calledOnPause)
{ // do permission checks
...
}
// else just call methods requiring the permissions

I think that just checking the boolean state would be easier way than doing fancy permission checks

Is there anything against my idea ?